# Macbook pro ATI GPU is fried. What are my options

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, macbook

I have an early 2011 15" Macbook (2.4 GHz i7)

The laptop boots fine, but

- after 10 to 20 minutes of regular use the screen either goes blank, breaks off into multiple lines, goes dark or just freezes the image
- one or two minutes after that happens it reboots
- If I connect the HDMI connector this happens in less than 5 minutes.

Ive run all the hardware diagnostics including memory tests and it says everything is fine.

Can I change just the GPU or do I need to change the whole logicboard?

Comment: What are the symptoms? Does it boot but fails to display an image? Doesn't it start at all, ... ?

Comment: @hennes just updated the description